# How to make svg as a layer in Leaflet.js

Tags: d3.js, svg, leaflet

Recently, I am doing a bubble map which using Leaflet.js. But it become painful when I want to make different layers to show bubbles with different colors. I came up with two solutions, but none of them can totally solve my problems.

Solution 1: Problem: I don't know how to assign the svg to a layer like:

```
var tiles = new L.LayerGroup();    tiles.addTo(Alltiles);
```

I also confused about this code:

```
map._initPathRoot()
```

Here is the code link: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9267535

Solution 2: I can draw different layers based on this code, but the Problem is: Zoomed d3.js circles fixed in geographic location on leaflet map but constant size.

Here is the code link: http://bl.ocks.org/xEviL/4921fff1d70f5601d159

I wonder anyone will have some references that I can use? Thank you.

Comment: What's your leaflet version?